# Is it possible to update the application icon on the iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone

I've noticed that the icon belonging to the Calendar app on the iPhone updates to show the latest day. Is there anything in the SDK that will let me do this in my apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible for third-party apps, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen this in any documentation, pretty sure it can only use the static icon.png file that is put in the ipa package. It would be an awesome feature though, I would recommend creating a feature request for it on https://bugreport.apple.com/. I specifically wish the weather app would update with your local weather for the icon.